# How can I have one recyclerview element using datas from another page?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-edittext

from this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS9B9.png)

to this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT4b6.png)

after clicking submit  button I want all fundraising descriptions turn into one recyclerview element.
In short, i need to do edittext->recyclerview, that's it.

I have no idea what to do. My code is in kotlin

Comment: You can have `state` and according to state you can inflate view ( use viewType to decide which view to inflate ). One more tip.. Try Epoxy it simplifies the process when having multiple layouts. Epoxy : https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy . Kindly let me know if you need any help.